# É possível fazer uma lista de seleção em forma de loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c

É possível fazer uma lista de seleção (`UIPickerView`) em forma de loop? Colocar o mês de janeiro logo após o de dezembro, eu digo.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sim, mas o método é meio que gambiarra, não existe um código automático pra isso tanto que a própria apple faz. Vou explicar;
Smplismente faça uma lista com 100 cópias da mesma sequência, depois faça com que esse picker se mova até a sequência nº50( item nº 50*12 meses).

Answer (score 1):

Assim como o `@Rivas` disse, não existe um jeito muito prático de se fazer. Vou tentar exemplificar um pouco melhor a explicação acima:

Você precisa multiplicar a quantidade de elementos por um número alto, 100, por exemplo, mas tome cuidado, pois dependendo do objeto utilizado, multiplicar por um número muito alto pode causar lentidão.

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return self.mesesArray.count * 100;
}
```

Em seguida, para obter corretamente o título é necessário utilizar o operador `mod` (`%`) para obter a linha correspondente aos 12 meses.

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return self.mesesArray[row % self.mesesArray.count];
}
```

E para finalizar posicione a seleção do `UIPicker` pelo meio da lista, ou alguma linha próxima. Faça isso em algum método de inicialização da view, como o `viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mesesArray = @[@"Janeiro",@"Fevereiro",@"Março",@"Abril",@"Maio",@"Junho",@"Julho",@"Agosto",@"Setembro",@"Outubro",@"Novembro",@"Dezembro"];

    [self.pickerView selectRow:self.mesesArray.count * 50
                   inComponent:0
                      animated:NO];

}
```

O resultado final este:

[image: Resultado do Picker circular]